# App crashed when sending images through TCP

Tags: java, sockets

I'm creating a simple stream to send images taken from client's screen from client to server. For now I can receive the first image but then the app crashed unexpectedly. The idea is send the size and the image in byte array, the server receive that byte array and convert to image.

FromClient:

```
    public void run() {

    image = new BufferedImage(NORM_PRIORITY, MIN_PRIORITY, MAX_PRIORITY);

    while(continueLoop) {

        //send captured screen
        image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

        try {
            //Initiate the stream
            OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);

            // store the size of each image
            byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(baos.size()).array();

            dos.write(size);                
            dos.write(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.toByteArray().length);
            dos.flush();

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
            continueLoop = false;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

ToServer:

```
   public void run() {
   boolean continueLoop = true;
   try {

       drawGUI();

       // Initiate the stream
       InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
       DataInputStream configGraphicStream = new DataInputStream(is);

       BufferedImage image = null;

       while(continueLoop) {

            //receive the size of image and convert to type int
            byte[] sizeInByte = new byte[64];
            configGraphicStream.read(sizeInByte);
            int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeInByte).asIntBuffer().get();

            try {
                // Get images
                byte[] img = new byte[length];
                configGraphicStream.readFully(img, 0, img.length);              
                image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(img));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }   

            //draw images
            if( image != null)
            {
                Graphics graphics = clientPanel.getGraphics();
                graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, clientPanel.getWidth(), clientPanel.getHeight(), clientPanel);
            }

            System.out.println("Receiving image");
            Thread.sleep(30);

       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: How does it crash?

Comment: It's freezed after receving the first image

Comment: is server crashed or client crashed? is there any stacktrace?

Comment: There is no stacktrace, I believe that the error from client side that can't send images continously and the server receive null.

Comment: You shouldn't initialize `out` and `dos` at **every** iteration of the loop on the client side. Doing it once is enough, since it's the same socket, just like you do on the server side.

Comment: This is not an application crash. It is a thread blocking. `sizeInByte[]` should be of size 4, not 64, but you don't need it, or the two lines following it. Just use `int length = DataInputStream.readInt()` to read the length, and `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` to write it at the sender. And don't flush inside loops, not that `DataOutputStream.flush()` actually does anything. You don't need the sleep at the receiver either: it will block while the sender is sleeping instead of sending.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @user207421 wow, It worked now but may I ask you few questions: 
1/ Why the sizeInByte[] should be size 4 ? 
2/ I want to send 30 frame per second but now the app was running  extremly slow and it's no where near 30, Is there still problem about the code?